# Disable background and change tint color for custom popup

Tags: objective-c, ios7, popup, tintcolor

In my project I created some custom popups. Just like for example the UIActionSheet I would like to create an overlay, disable other interactions and gray out the tintColor of the UITabBar buttons, UINavigationBar buttons and so on.

As for now I've managed to fix this by manually creating a background overlay, disable the interaction by adding this overlay over other views and change the tintcolor manually.

I've searched for an API method to automatically solve this problem, but without success. 
Hoping to find some good suggestions here at SO.

**Edit**

The answer I was looking for is called tintAdjustmentMode:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tintAdjustmentMode

Answer (score 0):

- Add a new view in your xib
- set background color as a black color and set the opacity to 50%
- Create your popup on this view.
- Put this view in the main view.
- Finally just hide & unhide this view according to your requirement.

In this you don't need to disable any other control.

Comment: As described in my question this is already the implementation I have. I'm searching for one generic API method to present a popup and automatically disable all other buttons and change their tint colors.